# error Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

getting an error. seem like error is with package name on line `Process: com.testpackage.digitalwallet, PID: 3041` I am not sure how to debug this

```
[TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead
[h.digitalwalle] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 64891(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 19(996KB) LOS objects, 53% free, 5MB/11MB, paused 50us total 30.478ms
[h.digitalwalle] No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff.
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: com.testpackage.digitalwallet, PID: 3041
[AndroidRuntime] android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceTypeName(ResourcesImpl.java:283)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName(Resources.java:2001)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentAnim.loadAnimation(FragmentAnim.java:79)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController$AnimationInfo.getAnimation(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:796)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.startAnimations(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:144)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.executeOperations(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:120)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.executePendingOperations(SpecialEffectsController.java:294)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2202)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
[AndroidRuntime]    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
```

Comment: that error/crash doesn't appear to have anything to do with your db.

Comment: Won't resource ID refer to an actual image for instance?

Comment: i checked and all my images in share project are `embedded resource` and images inside android-project are `android resource`. Also I tried clean & rebuild. any idea where issue could be or how can i debug it?

Comment: Did you try to delete the content of the Resource.designer.cs and rebuild the project ?

Comment: to be honest, I am kind of tired of this annoying error. Seem like with Xamarin.forms its very common error. I always end up deleting my whole project and starting from scratch, which sets me back atleast a week.. But I never though about only deleting content of `Resource.designer.cs` file and `clean/rebuild` it. @LeoZhu-MSFT Good idea!!! I will try this next time when i get this error agian... which will be soon

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing all of the `Xamarin.Android.Support.*` and `Xamarin.AndroidX.*` packages from my csproj files. I immediately stopped getting those errors.